# Airflow tasks not gettin running

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to run a simple BASHOperator task in Airflow. The DAG when trigerred manually lists the tasks in Tree and Graph view but the tasks are always in not started state.

I have restarted my Airflow scheduler. I am running Airflow on local host using a Kubectl image on Docker Compose.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['vijayraghunath21@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_success': True,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='bash_demo',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Bash Demo',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    # schedule_interval='0 2 * * *',
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
    tags=['bash_demo'],
) as dag:
    dag.doc_md = __doc__

    # Task 1
    dummy_task = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task')

    # Task 2
    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='bash_task', bash_command="echo 'command executed from BashOperator'")

    dummy_task >> bash_task
```

[DAG Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEefT.png)

Answer (score 1):

As shown on the image you added the DAG is set to off thus it's not running. You should click on the toggle button to set it to on.

[image]

This issue can be avoided in two ways:

Global solution- if you wills set `dags_are_paused_at_creation = False` in `airflow.cfg` - This will effect all DAGs in the system.

Local solution - if you will use `is_paused_upon_creation` in the DAG contractor:

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='bash_demo',
    ...
    is_paused_upon_creation=False,
) as dag:
```

This parameter specifies if the dag is paused when created for the first time. If the dag exists already, the parameter is being ignored.

Comment: Thanks Elad, the ruse worked. Will use this suggestion ``` is_paused_upon_creation=False,```  when creating the DAG contractor to test it.

Comment: @Vijay if solved please accept the answer